# How is the conversion of raisin to tannin and acid?

Tags: wine, ingredients, recipe-scaling, conversion, acidity

It's hard to find tannin powder as there is no wine making supplies in my country. There, I'd rather use raisin as tannin substitute in my wine making process. However, I'm not sure how the conversion of those thing. Anyone could give me some advice? The recipe needs 1/4 tsp of tannin and 1-1/2 tsp of acid blend.

Comment: I'm not sure how much tanin you'll find in raisins, but I'd consider using a black tea instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used black tea stewed for about 30-45 min, and used as my about half of my brewing water, if you want to try with raisins have a look here:

http://www.westchesterwinemakers.com/2013/05/31/x-18/